# robot_localization Build Failure

Tags: navigation, catkin, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; ROS Kinetic; catkin tools
robot_localization package git cloned to ~/catkin_ws/src

catkin build fails.  I do not understand the issue and would appreciate if someone could interpret the build output below and advise.

Thank you in advance.

---

```
karl@qqq:~/catkin_ws$ catkin build robot_localization 
Profile:                     default
Extending:          [cached] /opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/karl/catkin_ws
---------------------------------------------------------
Source Space:       [exists] /home/karl/catkin_ws/src
Log Space:          [exists] /home/karl/catkin_ws/logs
Build Space:        [exists] /home/karl/catkin_ws/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/karl/catkin_ws/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/karl/catkin_ws/install
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
---------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
---------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
---------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
---------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
---------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '11' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                                                                                                                                                
[build] Package table is up to date.                                                                                                                                                                       
Starting  >>> roscpp                                                                                                                                                                                       
Starting  >>> tf2                                                                                                                                                                                          
Starting  >>> tf2_ros                                                                                                                                                                                      
Finished  <<< roscpp                            [ 0.5 seconds ]                                                                                                                                            
Finished  <<< tf2_ros                           [ 0.3 seconds ]                                                                                                                                            
Finished  <<< tf2                               [ 0.3 seconds ]                                                                                                                                            
Starting  >>> robot_localization                                                                                                                                                                           
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Errors     << robot_localization:make /home/karl/catkin_ws/logs/robot_localization/build.make.001.log                                                                                                      
CMakeFiles/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.dir/test/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp.o: In function `main':
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster::StaticTransformBroadcaster()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x25a): undefined reference to `ros::ok()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x7ac): undefined reference to `tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster::sendTransform(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x865): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x874): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x883): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x8f4): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x925): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x956): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0x995): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0xa96): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0xaaa): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text+0xabe): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
CMakeFiles/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.dir/test/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp.o: In function `tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster::~StaticTransformBroadcaster()':
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZN7tf2_ros26StaticTransformBroadcasterD2Ev[_ZN7tf2_ros26StaticTransformBroadcasterD5Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZN7tf2_ros26StaticTransformBroadcasterD2Ev[_ZN7tf2_ros26StaticTransformBroadcasterD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZN7tf2_ros26StaticTransformBroadcasterD2Ev[_ZN7tf2_ros26StaticTransformBroadcasterD5Ev]+0x50): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZN7tf2_ros26StaticTransformBroadcasterD2Ev[_ZN7tf2_ros26StaticTransformBroadcasterD5Ev]+0x61): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
CMakeFiles/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.dir/test/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp.o: In function `ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, bool)':
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros10NodeHandle9advertiseIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEEENS_9PublisherERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjb[_ZN3ros10NodeHandle9advertiseIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEEENS_9PublisherERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjb]+0xdd): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::advertise(ros::AdvertiseOptions&)'
CMakeFiles/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.dir/test/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp.o: In function `ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise<geometry_msgs::AccelWithCovarianceStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, bool)':
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros10NodeHandle9advertiseIN13geometry_msgs27AccelWithCovarianceStamped_ISaIvEEEEENS_9PublisherERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjb[_ZN3ros10NodeHandle9advertiseIN13geometry_msgs27AccelWithCovarianceStamped_ISaIvEEEEENS_9PublisherERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjb]+0xdd): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::advertise(ros::AdvertiseOptions&)'
CMakeFiles/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.dir/test/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp.o: In function `void ros::Publisher::publish<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > >(nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > const&) const':
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZNK3ros9Publisher7publishIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEEEvRKT_[_ZNK3ros9Publisher7publishIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEEEvRKT_]+0x371): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::Impl::isValid() const'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZNK3ros9Publisher7publishIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEEEvRKT_[_ZNK3ros9Publisher7publishIN8nav_msgs9Odometry_ISaIvEEEEEvRKT_]+0xbfc): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::publish(boost::function<ros::SerializedMessage ()> const&, ros::SerializedMessage&) const'
CMakeFiles/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.dir/test/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp.o: In function `void ros::Publisher::publish<geometry_msgs::AccelWithCovarianceStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::AccelWithCovarianceStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&) const':
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZNK3ros9Publisher7publishIN13geometry_msgs27AccelWithCovarianceStamped_ISaIvEEEEEvRKT_[_ZNK3ros9Publisher7publishIN13geometry_msgs27AccelWithCovarianceStamped_ISaIvEEEEEvRKT_]+0x371): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::Impl::isValid() const'
test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.cpp:(.text._ZNK3ros9Publisher7publishIN13geometry_msgs27AccelWithCovarianceStamped_ISaIvEEEEEvRKT_[_ZNK3ros9Publisher7publishIN13geometry_msgs27AccelWithCovarianceStamped_ISaIvEEEEEvRKT_]+0xbfc): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::publish(boost::function<ros::SerializedMessage ()> const&, ros::SerializedMessage&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/karl/catkin_ws/devel/.private/robot_localization/lib/robot_localization/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [all] Error 2
cd /home/karl/catkin_ws/build/robot_localization; catkin build --get-env robot_localization | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j; cd -
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................
Failed     << robot_localization:make           [ Exited with code 2 ]                                                                                                                                     
Failed    <<< robot_localization                [ 18.1 seconds ]                                                                                                                                           
[build] Summary: 3 of 4 packages succeeded.                                                                                                                                                                
[build]   Ignored:   7 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.                                                                                                                                           
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                                                                                                                                                 
[build]   Abandoned: None.                                                                                                                                                                                 
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                                                                                                                                                    
[build] Runtime: 19.0 seconds total.                                                                                                                                                                       
karl@qqq:~/catkin_ws$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276173/robot_localization-build-failure/) by [Marvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32593/marvin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2017-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I never found out how to build the robot_localization package cloned from git using catkin tools.  However, I discovered that the robot_localization package could be installed simply using: sudo apt-get install ros--robot-localization

---

Originally posted by [Marvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32593/marvin/) with karma: 91 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0